# How can I post a form with text as a stream to PHP to avoid browser post limit?

Tags: php, post, browser, stream, limit

Web browsers have a limit to how much data (characters) can be posted to prevent attacks. In IE its roughly 2000 characters, and in Chrome its around 65,000.

I'm trying to post a form that has a field containing 200,000+ characters (a json strong of vectors to be precise).

This is way more than any browser will allow, so the PHP page that receives the post only sees about 40% of the data.

The only way I can think of getting around this is to stream the form post so that PHP can receive it incrementally.

Is this possible to do with $raw = file_get_contents('php://input'); in combination with a form encoding type of "application/octet-stream" for example?

Many thanks,
Seb

Comment: the only limits on POST are the server/php limits - think file upload

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with PHP under Linux or similar, you can control these using `.htaccess`, like so:

```
#set max post size
php_value post_max_size 50M
```

Hope this will allow you to send more data rather than messing up with coding.

> The url portion of a request (GET and POST) can be limited by both the
>   browser and the server - generally the safe size is 2KB as there are
>   almost no browsers or servers that use a smaller limit.
>
> The body of a request (POST) is normally* limited by the server on a
>   byte size basis in order to prevent a type of DoS attack (note that
>   this means character escaping can increase the byte size of the body).
>   The most common server setting is 10MB, though all popular servers
>   allow this to be increased or decreased via a setting file or panel.

Comment: my post_max_size is set to 100M. Interestingly, if I inspect the POST request using Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com), it appears all the data is being sent. But if I do file_get_contents('php://input'), only half the data is printed. Is there some other buffer/limit to be aware of for large text POSTs?

Comment: according to my knowledge I don't think so but let me work on it and try to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing URL length limits with upload limits. Data passed via URLs is a `GET` query, and those ARE length-limited on a per-browser basis.

If you need to pass arbitrary "large" data, then you use POST, which has no arbitrary client-side length limits and is subject only to the server configured limits.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - found what the problem was. Data was travelling through a WAF filter before reaching Apache. This is running mod_security which had a post limit of 64Kb.